# Updating File in Express

Tags: node.js, express, file

I am new to NodeJs and have created a Node application. The user has to upload the html files from the ui.. and then I am supposed to update the file with a few requirements to make the page workable.

Considering an Example :-

```
  <meta name="description" content="">
  
  <title>xyz</title>(The xyz can be any word)
```

The Uploaded File contains these two lines, And I want to remove the first line and replace the other line with the lines that i require to be there.

I tried

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile("./index.html", {encoding: 'utf8'}, function (err,data) {
    var formatted = data.replace("<title>xyz</title>", 'This new line replaces the old line');
fs.writeFile("your file", formatted, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
 });
});
```

I don't Know How to do it .. But as the value of xyz changes the above function does not work.. Therefore how can I make it generalized.

Thanks For Any Help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have two solutions in mind:

1. use a regular expression
2. use an html parser like https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser

i'm gonna answer with the second one because i think it's better in this case:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs')
const parser = require( 'node-html-parser');
const {parse} = parser

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    fs.readFile("./index.html", {encoding: 'utf8'}, function (err,data) {
    var root = parse(data) 
    // don't forget to use 'myTitle' as id in your html file
    root.querySelector("#myTitle").replaceWith("what you wanna replace with")
    fs.writeFile("your file", root.toString(), 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
 });
});
    res.end('file modified!');
});

server.listen( 3000);
```